# Find, with proof, the smallest possible value of S

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be real value numbers $>1$, and let $$S=\log_a(bc)+\log_b(ca)+\log_c(ab),$$ where $log_b(x)$ denotes the base $b$ logarithm of x. Find, with proof, the smallest possible value of S.

Is there someone who can give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum value is $6$......Let $$F=\log_a bc +\log_b ca +\log_c ab.$$Let $$\ln a =p , \ln b= q , \ln c =r.$$ Then $p,q,r$ are positive...... Let $$p/q=x , q/r=y , r/p=z.$$ Then $x,y,z$ are positive. We have $$F =(q+r)/p +(r+p)q + (p+q)/r$$ $$ =(p/q+q/p)+(q/r+r/q)+(r/p+p/r)$$  $$=(x+1/x)+(y+1/y)+(z+1/z).$$ For $x>0$ we have $x+1/x=(\sqrt x -1/\sqrt x)^2+2\ge 2$ with equality iff $x=1.$ Similarly for $y+1/y$ and $z+1/z$......Hence $F\ge 2+2+2=6$ with equality iff  $x=y=z=1$ iff $p=q=r=1$ iff $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that
$$
\log_r s=\frac{\log s}{\log r}
$$
where the unadorned “log” can be in any base (say $e$). So you have to minimize
$$
S=\frac{\log b+\log c}{\log a}+\frac{\log c+\log a}{\log b}+
\frac{\log a+\log b}{\log c}
$$
that is the same as minimizing
$$
S=\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{z+x}{y}+\frac{x+y}{z}
$$
where $x,y,z>0$.

Can you take from here?

Comment: One can of course use standard Calculus techniques to get the answer. I'm curious, though, if there's an argument to be made from symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: $\log_a (b)$ and $\log_b (a)$ are reciprocals of each other.